# MySQL List some field from a single table and COUNT all particular field reference from another table

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join, inner-join

The subject of my question is a bit confusing because I'm running out of words to suit the general and technical description of it.

In a less technical terms, what I'm trying to accomplish specifically is:

> List all churches and their corresponding booking status from a service they are offering with the following fields:

- Church id **AS** `id`
- Church name **AS** `name`
- Count of `pending` status from all services they are offering **AS** `pendingCount`
- Count of `fully booked` status from all services they are offering **AS** `bookedCount`

The structure of associate tables are as follows:

### Church

```
+---------+---------------+
| id(int) | name(varchar) |
+---------+---------------+
```

### Services

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+
| id(int) | name(varchar) | churchId(int) |
+---------+---------------+---------------+
```

### Bookings

```
+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| id(int) | status(varchar) | serviceId(int) |
+---------+-----------------+----------------+
```

What I have come up so far is this, which I'm totally have no idea why it is compiling but produces a negative result:

```
SELECT
    churches.id,
    churches.name,
    pending.count AS pendingCount,
    booked.count AS bookedCount
FROM
    churches
INNER JOIN
    services
ON
    services.churchId = churches.id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        COUNT(bookings.id) AS `count`,
        bookings.serviceId
     FROM
        bookings
     WHERE
        bookings.status = 'pending'
     GROUP BY
        bookings.serviceId)
     AS pending
ON
    pending.serviceId = services.id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        COUNT(bookings.id) AS `count`,
        bookings.serviceId
     FROM
        bookings
     WHERE
        bookings.status = 'fully booked'
     GROUP BY
        bookings.serviceId)
     AS booked
ON
    booked.serviceId = services.id
```

### Sample output

[image]

Comment: Your question is not too clear to me.  Could you include some sample output?  I think you should do this even if you accept the answers below.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help a lot. My answer is untested, it would be nice to verify it and correct it if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your time reading my question. The example output has been added as requested :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use conditional aggregation for this. It is a way to sum a number of rows that meet a certain value. In this case, we can use aggregation for `SUM(b.status = 'fullyBooked')` and `SUM(b.status = 'pending')` and group by church `id` like this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name,
    SUM(b.status = 'pending') AS pendingCount,
    SUM(b.status = 'fully booked') AS bookedCount
FROM bookings b
RIGHT JOIN services s ON s.id = b.serviceId
RIGHT JOIN churches c ON c.id = s.churchid
GROUP BY c.id;
```

To reiterate, by using `SUM(condition)` and grouping by a certain `id` value, you are counting the number of times that condition is true for that `id` value.

---

**EDIT**:

I have added a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` to this query so that churches without any bookings will be returned as well.

Comment: Hmm, but it only outputs `churches` who have a reference from another table, how could I make a default value, like e.g 0 if they're not present?

Comment: May want a left join to show churches that have no bookings.

Comment: @JRD I have tried to prepend it with `LEFT` but seems not working though :/

Comment: @mr5 the reason `LEFT` did not work in my example is because I have joined the churches table last. My particular query needs a `RIGHT` outer join to get churches without bookings.

Comment: @McAdam331, Have never seen the SUM(boolean) before, I like. I usually default to a count(if ...) or count(case when ...), but like this one better.

Comment: @JRD Thanks! Essentially it is the same as `COUNT(CASE..)`. You will get the same result. I'm not sure what the performance difference is, but I definitely find this more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.id, c.name,
       SUM(b.status = 'pending') pendingCount,
       SUM(b.status = 'fully booked') bookedCount
from   church c
-- Left join here if you want all churches whether or not they offer a service
left join services s on (c.id = s.churchId)
-- Left join here if you want all churches w/ a service, but may have no bookings
left join bookings b on (s.id = b.serviceId)
group by c.id, c.name;
```

Comment: I never thought it was this easy. Your SQL statement is less complex than everyone else's answer and satisfies my general need.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
    churches.id,
    churches.name,
    count(case when bookings.status = 'pending' then 1 else null end) AS pendingCount,
    count(case when bookings.status = 'fully booked' then 1 else null end) AS bookedCount
FROM
    churches
INNER JOIN
    services
ON
    services.churchId = churches.id
LEFT JOIN bookings on bookings.serviceId=services.id
group by 
    churches.id,
    churches.name,
```

Comment: Hmm, but it produces an error `Unknown column 'bookings.status' in 'field list'`?

Comment: Amended, forgot to join on bookings table

Comment: Hmm, seems working though but I have replaced `INNER LEFT JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`